Questioning the Probability Expression for Neutrino Oscillation in Griffiths' "Introduction to Elementary Particles"
In Griffiths' book, Introduction to Elementary Particles (Griffiths, D. (2020). John Wiley & Sons, p. 390), the author defines the pure electron and muon neutrino states as:
$$|ν_{e}\rangle=-\sinθ|ν_1\rangle+\cosθ|ν_1\rangle$$ and
$$|ν_{μ}\rangle=\cosθ|ν_1\rangle+\sinθ|ν_2\rangle$$
Thus, the time evolution of a neutrino initially produced as an electron neutrino is given by:
$$|ν(t)\rangle=-\sinθ\mathrm{e}^{-(i/\hbar)E_1t}|ν_1\rangle+\cosθ\mathrm{e}^{-(i/\hbar)E_2t}|ν_2\rangle$$
The probability for that neutrino to transform into a muon neutrino is then:
$$P(ν_{e}→ν_{μ})=|\langle ν_{μ}\vert ν(t)\rangle|^2$$
Expanding this, we get:
$$P(ν_{e}→ν_{μ})={[\langle ν_1|(\cosθ)+|\langle ν_2|(\sinθ)][-\sinθ\mathrm{e}^{-(i/\hbar)E_1t}|ν_1\rangle+\cosθ\mathrm{e}^{-(i/\hbar)E_2t}|ν_2\rangle]}$$
However, the author expresses it as:
$$P(ν_{e}→ν_{μ})=|ν_{μ}|²$$
which seems more like a normalization relation rather than an oscillation probability.
Can anyone provide their opinion on this matter?

Apologies, in my earlier answer I had not seen the  book (could access the earlier version, which has your typo).
The transition/overlap  amplitude at time t between these two states is, as you set it up,
$$
\langle \nu_\mu|\nu (t)\rangle =\sin \theta \cos\theta ~(e^{-iE_2t/\hbar} -e^{-iE_t/\hbar} )\\
={\sin 2\theta \over 2} ~(e^{-iE_2t/\hbar} -e^{-iE_t/\hbar} ).
$$
It is this transition amp that is abs-squared, and not his typo/complacent $|\nu_\mu|^2$. you may, in fact, verify from the above that
$$P(ν_{e} \to ν_{μ} )~=|\langle ν_{μ}|ν(t)\rangle |^2\\   
=\left[\sin 2\theta ~~\sin \left({E_2-E_1\over 2\hbar} t \right) \right]^2,$$
the expression he correctly has.
Your text evaluates this right.
Just for fun, you could calculate the flavor persistence probability $
P(ν_{e} \to ν_{e} )~=|\langle ν_{e}|ν(t)\rangle |^2,
$ and confirm that it is 1 minus (the above).

I think I've identified the issue, and it seems to be related to the notation used by the author.
When we define the state
$$|ψ(t)>=cosθe^{-(i/ℏ)E₁t}|ν₁>+sinθe^{-(i/ℏ)E₂t}|ν₂>$$
in terms of the mass eigenstates rather than the flavour eigenstates, we get
$$|ψ(t)>=(cos²θe^{-(i/ℏ)E₁t}+sin²θe^{-(i/ℏ)E₂t})|ν_{e}>+sinθcosθ(e^{-(i/ℏ)E₂t}-e^{-(i/ℏ)E₁t})|ν_{μ}>$$
which can be expressed more compactly by
$$|ψ(t)>=A|ν_{e}>+B|ν_{μ}>$$
with $A=(cos²θe^{-(i/ℏ)E₁t}+sin²θe^{-(i/ℏ)E₂t})$ and $B=sinθcosθ(e^{-(i/ℏ)E₂t}-e^{-(i/ℏ)E₁t})$.
The probability (notation) changes accordingly. We get
$$P(ν_{e}→ν_{μ})=|<ν_{μ}||ψ(t)>|²=|B|²$$
This adjustment clarifies that the confusion arises from the notation used for the coefficient $B$. The author used the same symbol for the pure state $ν_{μ}$​ itself, which led to the misunderstanding. By distinguishing between the coefficients and the states more clearly, we can avoid this type of confusion.
